# c++ Posterior Decrement Operator Overloading Value Passing Problems

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

I'm using vs2022 and I'm confused about the c++ post-decrement operator overloading value passing, why does overloading a function that returns a value instead of a reference also affect the object itself?

I tried to return a reference, aka MyInteger& operator--(int), and the output is consistent with a value return, both changing the value of the object itself. Why does the post-decrement operator have to return a value instead of a reference, and why does returning a value also change the value of the object itself?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class MyInteger {
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& cout, MyInteger myint);
public:
    MyInteger() {
        m_int = 0;
    }
    MyInteger& operator--() {
       m_int--;
        return *this;
    }
    MyInteger operator--(int) {
        MyInteger myint  = *this;
        //myint = *this;
        m_int--;
        return myint;
    }
private:
    int m_int;
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& cout, MyInteger myint) {
    cout << myint.m_int;
    return cout;
}

void test() {
    MyInteger myint;
    cout << myint << endl;
    cout << --myint << endl;
    cout << myint << endl;
    cout << myint-- << endl;
    cout << (myint--)-- << endl;
    cout << myint << endl;
}

int main()  
{
    test();
    system("pause");
    system("cls");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The postfix operator has to return the "current" state of your object so it makes a copy of that and returns that copy and it will then increment the state of your object. So it is needed for correct behavior of the postfix operator

Comment: It's not the returning that modifies the object, it is the modification of `m_int`.

Comment: Practically, it probably doesn't make a difference whether it's `--m_int;` or `m_int--;` as `m_int` is just an `int`. However, with the intention to write the least confusing code I wouldn't implement a pre-fix decrement with a post-fix decrement. I prevent post-fix inc./dec. in general and use them only there where I have specific reason. Your code is a good example why it's worth: The pre-fix doesn't need the copy the post-fix has to do to return the previous state.

Comment: _why does overloading a function that returns a value instead_ This is the precise reason why there are prefix _and_ postfix inc./dec. operators: You can either inc. and use the new value (prefix) or inc. and use the old value (postfix). This is an inheritage from C but still useful sometimes to write more compact code though it might be considered as micro optimization. When these operators were introduced in C (decades ago) the resources of computers were still that limited that such options for optimization were valuable.

Comment: A possible way to look at it is that for a `T t;`, a `--t` works like `T& operator-- () { --my_value_; return *this; }` whereas a `t--` needs to keep and then return the previous value, which will be (unsurprisingly) temporary, as in `T operator-- (int) { T previous{*this}; --my_value_; return previous; }`. Whether `t--` does or doesn’t change `t`, that is entirely up to you. Nothing prevents you from implementing a non-standard `--` for `T` which fails to change `t`. However, this is not recommended due to readability concerns; prefer a non-operator method for such functionality.